# Is there a way to change all borders of all tables in Google Docs at once?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to change **all** border width of **all** tables in my document to 0.

Below you'll find the script that I'm using, when I try to run it it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

I've filled in my DOCUMENT_ID but removed it in the snippet below.

```
function setTableProperties() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById("DOCUMENT_ID");
  var tables = doc.getBody().getTables();

  tables.forEach((table) => {
               table.setBorderWidth(0);
  });
}
```

Comment: `0` means no border right?

Comment: I think that your script works. For example, in your script, when `tables[0].setBorderWidth(0)` is run, the border of 1st table is removed. So can I ask you about the detail of `it doesn't work.`?

Comment: I have the same problem. When I run the script, my document doesn't change at all even if log tell me that the table are there. Is there any right to add on the document?